# Conditional expected value when conditioning on a set of values

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Consider the random variables $Y,X,Z$ with supports $\mathcal{Y},\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Z}$, respectively.

Suppose that $E(Y|X=x,Z=z)=0$ for each $(x,z)\in \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Z}$.

Does this imply that
$$
E(Y| X\in \{x,x'\}, Z\in \{z,z'\})=0
$$
for any $x,x'\in \mathcal{X}$, $z,z'\in \mathcal{Z}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is 'yes', which can be shown by iterating the expectation.

\begin{align}
&E(Y|X\in\{x,x'\}, Z\in\{z,z'\})\\
&\quad= E\left(E(Y|X, X\in\{x,x'\},Z, Z\in\{z,z'\})|X\in\{x,x'\}, Z\in\{z,z'\}\right)\\
&\quad=E\left(E(Y|X, Z)|X\in\{x,x'\}, Z\in\{z,z'\}\right)\\
&\quad =0
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it holds.
$$\begin{align}E[Y|X\in\{x,x'\},Z\in\{z,z'\}]&=E[E[Y|X\in\{x,x'\},Z\in\{z,z'\},X=x,Z=z]]\\&=E[E[Y|X=x,Z=z]]\\&=E[0]=0\end{align}$$

Comment: Your proposed counterexample does not apply because it does not satisfy the premise of the original question, which requires that $E(Y|X = x, Z = z) = 0$ for all  $(x,z)\in \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Z}$. In contrast, in your counterexample, $E(Y|X=0, Z= 1) = E(Y|X=1, Z= 1) =1$

Comment: Thanks: this example does not satisfy my assumption that is $E(Y|X=x, Z=z)=0$ for each $x,z$. When $Z=1$, $E(Y|X=0, Z=1)=1$. When $Z=0$, $E(Y|X=0, Z=0)=0$.

Comment: Thanks @psboonstra! I noticed the same

Comment: My bad, I misread it.